# EntityFramework CodeFirst and EDMX together in TransactionScope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, msdtc

I need to combine in one application

1. code generated from DB to EDMX file before compilation and
2. code generated and compiled during runtime by application itself, where generated code uses CodeFirst to access DB.

Remark: Codes in 1. and 2. have different DbContexts, access same database, but different tables.

It looks, that when I am using instances of type 1. and 2. in different transaction scopes, everything works fine. But when I try to use them together in one transaction scope, I get error (in case when EDMX is called first)

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation. ---> System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error
occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be cause
d by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exce
ptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System
.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: **The provider did not return a ProviderManif
estToken string.** ---> System.Transactions.TransactionException: **The operation is
 not valid for the state of the transaction.**
```

and error (in case when CodeFirst is used first)

```
System.Data.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
(0,0) : error 0175: **The specified store provider cannot be found in the configur
ation, or is not valid.**
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
```

To complicate my situation even more I have to add this: described behaviour I have only in case when DB is on remote server. If I am working with local DB, everything looks OK. My suspicion is that Distributed Transaction Coordinator can play its role...

Main question: is it possible to combine EDMX and CodeFirst in one TransactionScope. If yes then how?

Any help would be appreciated. Milos

Comment: What database are you using and how your config files look like.

Comment: Database: MS SQL Server 2008 CodeFirst connection string: @"Server=nyx; Database=Workflow3; Trusted_Connection=true; Enlist=True;" EDMX connection string: metadata=res://AppFrameworkLibrary/AppFrameworkLibrary.csdl|res://AppFrameworkLi‌​brary/AppFrameworkLibrary.ssdl|res://AppFrameworkLibrary/AppFrameworkLibrary.msl;‌​provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=nyx;Initial Catalog=Workflow3;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Enlist=True;"

Comment: With codefirst you should not have neither EDMX nor the Entity connection string. CodeFirst internally creates the model (i.e. edmx) based on your classes.

Answer (score 0):

CodeFirst creates an EDMX based on your classes and it's not possible to load an exisiting edmx file. However you can generate classes from your database (e.g. using EF Power Tools) and configure your model so that the EDMX generated by your CodeFirst app is the same as the one you would like to load. You can use TransactionScope with Entity Framework. The error messages you are getting are not related to transaction scope but to a missing or incorrectly used provider.

Answer (score 0):

I used code first to save to two different databases came up with errors connection string was wrong so i did this and it worked....

```
try
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        MegaBotExtractorDBContext2 db = new MegaBotExtractorDBContext2();
        MegaBotExtractorDBContext db1 = new MegaBotExtractorDBContext();
        FullUri newUri = new FullUri();
        HostUri NewHostUri = new HostUri { HostUriName = "google10.com" };
        db1.HostUris.Add(NewHostUri);
        db1.SaveChanges();

        using (TransactionScope ts2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            db.FullUris.Add(newUri);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ts2.Complete();
            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
}
catch { }
```